# Searching for a not known number in searchbars(google, youtube, ...)

Tags: search, youtube

I'm seaching for a way to find a series of numbers in a text.
This can either be a youtube description or just a news feed message.

So what i need is a way to search for numbers, where i know the length of, but don't know the numbers.

Example:

searching for => 123456789 (BUT i don't know the last 2 numbers)
so i would like to search for => 1234567**

Unfortunately, you can't use * in searchbars.
I tried some query related stuff, like * or % but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know a way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .. in google to search for not known numbers.

Example: 1234567.. or 123456..

This doesn't work in youtube unfortunately.

Comment: Still, i want to do something like this 12????????. And this give me all combination with 9 numbers starting with 12